# Add custom block before main content only on the contact page

Tags: magento-2.1, custom, static-block, widgets

i would like to add a static block between the nav menu en the content  so i can give it the full width of the page. This block must only be visible for the contact us page.

**System**: magento 2.1

**Theme**: destino

**File path**: /app/design/frontend/Sm/destino/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml

content of contact_index_index.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="contact.custom.block" before="main.content">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="contact-maps" after="breadcrumbs">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">contact-maps</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
```

See image below:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this /app/design/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml file and paste this.

```
 <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="contact.custom.block" before="main.content">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="cms-block-identifier">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">home_banner_top</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

create `/app/design/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml` file and paste this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="contact.custom.block" after="breadcrumbs">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="cms-block-identifier">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cms-block-identifier</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: OP asked before `text` not before the contact form.

Comment: The text is added in `form.phtml` itself.

Comment: i tried your solutions and it works, but i can't set the width of the block to full width because it is know inside the form 'wrapper'

Comment: @naknak12 see my updated answer.

Comment: i changed the 'cms-block-identifier' to contact-maps as that is the name of my block. But nothing appears. I also modified the original file but then also nothing changes on the page. (i cleared the cache)

Comment: @naknak12 This is working good here. please paste your file path and content in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by content and file path?

Comment: The path of file `contact_index_index.xml` you created and what you have in that file.

Comment: @SachinAgarwal I've modified my question

Comment: @naknak12 you need to move your `after="breadcrumbs"` attribute. see my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75295/discussion-between-naknak12-and-sachin-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

Try this /app/design/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml file and add this code.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="contact.map.block" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="contact-map" after="main.content">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="contact-map">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">contact_map</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```